# How can I extract the *.icns from the Get Info dialog?

Tags: macos, icon

Previously, I've changed the icon of an application before by manually replacing the icon file `.icns` located in `loremipsum.app/Contents/Resources/loremipsum.icns`.

This time, I've downloaded some [beautiful icons](http://iconfactory.com/freeware/preview/cab1) which are folders with the needed icon and not simple `.icns` files.

How can I get access of the the `*.icns` file?

[image]

Comment: Let me get this straight. You have an application for which you'd like to change the icon, and you can't figure out where it stores its icon file?

Comment: Or, from the title of your question, maybe you just want to get the icon from the app. You can mark it in the Get Info dialog, go Edit → Copy, switch to Preview, and select File → New from clipboard.

Comment: I know where the application's icon is located. The problem is that the icon I want to replace it with is not stored in a *.icns file. I only got the folder like in the picture.

Comment: I see. Shouldn't the question then be about how to create a `*.icns` file (from existing graphics)?

Comment: Is that what were are doing here? Like converting a thumbnail to a *.icns?

Comment: Ho hum. Posts crossing paths. Answer posted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can mark it in the Get Info dialog, go Edit → Copy, switch to Preview, and select File → New from clipboard.

Comment: This approach does not allow the file to be saved as ```.icns``` but saves it as a regular image.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to edit a resource bundle. You can copy the icon from an existing folder, file or application by selecting it and choosing *Get Info* from the Finder **File** menu or by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

Select the icon file in the upper left hand corner by clicking on it once. The *copy* the file. I use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> for this. Now *Get Info* for the application you want to use the icon for. Select it's icon, and *paste* the new icon into the application using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! While this is true, I really wanted the `.icns` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free [iCondubber](http://icondubber.blogspot.co.uk/), which is a sort of universal icon manager/converter.

Comment: This app does not exist anymore, sorry but we have to downvote till you remove it. Nothing personal ;)